# Fixed width in facebook fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, fan-page

I am working on a `fanpage` where I need to upload whole of the site on the `fanpage`. It means that the site is completely shown on the `fanpage`. As you know that the width of the `fanpage` is maximum 720px. Can there be a way I can shrinkup the site and show it on the `fanpage`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fan page width is not **720px** its **520px**  and to show the website on the fanpage you need to re-design using max width 520px that will solve the problem or you can add the scroll bar at the bottom of the page to navigate horizontally .

If you want to use 2nd method you need to use this code block too

```
FB.init({ appId : APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth:true});

var obj =   new Object;
obj.width=1024;
obj.height=960;
FB.Canvas.setSize(obj);
```

Using this code block you can set the custom width and height of the page , but if the width exceeds **520px** the page will show the scroll bar at the bottom .

Wish you good luck !