# Facebook Tab App canvas stuck at 800px height

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, height, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to develop and app and the canvas size is fixed at 800px. I would like it to extend further than the 800px height. All the content below it gets cut off.

This code comes right after the  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId : 'APP_ID_HERE',
        status : true, // check login status
        channelUrl : '/channel.html', // Channel File
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is a Facebook tab app.

Comment: Is there anything useful in your Javascript console?

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398054/fixed-width-in-facebook-fanpage/8398983#8398983